# Methods for Dimensionality Reduction while Preserving Statistical and Correlational Features

Tags: time-series, correlation, dimensionality-reduction

I am working with a dataset comprising $k$ matrices, each representing different asset classes such as Stocks, Bonds, Linkers. Each matrix is of size $m \times n$, with $m$ being 10,000 simulations of $n$-year returns for these asset classes. Each entry in a matrix is a real number indicating the yearly return for a specific year and simulation. The primary goal is to reduce the number of simulations due to computational constraints in other models that use these datasets, which analyze all 10,000 simulations across each year. The challenge is to maintain statistical robustness and the integrity of time series and inter-matrix relationships during this reduction.

Key properties that need preservation include statistical robustness within each dataset, such as the preservation of mean, variance (standard deviation), skewness, and kurtosis of the yearly returns. Time series characteristics like autocorrelation and volatility clustering are important as well in my opinion. And inter-matrix relationships such as correlations and the covariance matrix structure between different asset classes must be maintained to capture their interplay over time.

I am looking for recommendations on statistical methods or algorithms effective in reducing the number of simulations while preserving these statistical and time series properties. Are there established methodologies, literature, or case studies specifically addressing these requirements in financial time series? Besides the properties listed, are there other crucial aspects to consider in the dimensionality reduction process, particularly for financial time series? Insights, experiences, and suggestions including theoretical advice, practical applications, or software/tool recommendations, are highly appreciated.

Comment: Re "Which properties are crucial to preserve": Isn't that entirely a matter of why you're doing this and what your data mean?  I think we will need more specific information of this sort before we can offer thoughtful, focused, or objective answers.

Comment: Thanks @whuber, I will add clarity on the question and for what it is needed.